# Fronted issue after inline translation

Tags: magento-1.9, inline-translations

As you can See in bellow pic, my inline translation is disabled, but I am getting inline translate option in fronted.

[image]

and fronted is 
[image]

I have two stores, English and Dutch, inline translation is appearing on English, Dutch version if fine. as shown

Dutch
[image]

English

[image]

Comment: I think issue related to cache.

Comment: All cache's are disabled,

Comment: check the store level may enable some points..

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you.

Comment: check the configuration for your current website and current store

Comment: I didn't find any think, In the case of Dutch store, just language is being changes in  **Locale**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the inline translation config at website and store level and clear the caché. Test it in a private mode browser.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your inline translation is disable for perticular english store by selecting it from top left corner, i think you have selected default scope

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the cache ('Blocks HTML output'). Just flush cache ('Flush Magento Cache').